# Textfield is not made visible when the radio form element is checked

Tags: forms

In my form I have the following:

```
$form['text_2'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Text'),
    '#default_value' => isset($config['text_2']) ? $config['text_2'] : '',
    '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
            ':input[name="search_radio"]' => ['checked' => true],
        ],
    ]
];
```

The search_radio field is:

```
$form['search_radio'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => $this->t('Enable radio buttons'),
  '#default_value' => isset($config['search_radio']) ? $config['search_radio'] : false,
);
```

Checking and unchecking the search_radio field has no effect at all on this field.

Comment: Can you post your "search_radio" field also?

Comment: I've added it, above.

Comment: Above code working good in my system Can you post any attachments if possible?
So that it will be good to look more. Also check is there any JS errors in page.

Comment: What type of attachments?  There is no console activity whatsoever when checking and unchecking.

Comment: I have it working. Switching from name= to data-drupal-selector= seems to have overcome whatever the issue was.